# RegEx for matching repetitive strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Searching product names & product description crom CSV for filter volts with regex what im trying to do is remove duplicate values from my search.
I have tried set list etc Im struggling to understand why I can not remove duplicate words from my search. not understanding how set works it seems to split all values into charactors 1,2, , v,o,l,t can one not just remove whole duplicate word in found? when I run the code I get:

```
12 Volt
12 Volt
40 Volt
2 Volt
18 Volt
18 Volt
240 Volt
240 Volt
110 Volt
110 Volt
110 Volt
36 Volt
```

What I need and struggling to achieive is unique list of values  I.E 12 Volt, 40 Volt, 18 Volt, 240 Volt etc etc

```
def volts_search():
    with open('filters/volts_filter.csv', 'w') as headerOut:
        headerOut.write("name" + "," + "sort_order" + "," + "status" + "," + "image" + "," + "regex" + "," + "value" + "\n")

    with open(merchant_feed, 'r') as csv_filein, open('filters/volts_filter.csv', 'a') as fileOut:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_filein, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in reader:
            program_name = clean_text(row['program_name'])
            product_name = clean_text(row['product_name'])
            product_description = clean_text(row['description'])
            merchant_category = clean_text(row['merchant_category'])
            product_id = row['product_id']
            product_brand = clean_text(row['brand'])

            filter_name = "Filter By Volts:"
            v = re.findall(r"((?i)(?:)\d+\.\d+v|\d+\.\d+ v|\d+ v|\d+v)", product_name + product_description)

            volt = re.findall(r"((?i)(?:)\d+volt|\d+ volt)", product_name + product_description)

            volts = re.findall(r"((?i)(?:)\d+\.\d+volts|\d+volts)", product_name + product_description)

            seen = set()
            for filter_search in volt:
                if filter_search in product_name + product_description:
                    if filter_search in seen: continue
                    seen.add(filter_search)

                    print(filter_search)
```

Comment: also a little more context would be useful.

Comment: why cant you use a set?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add additional information to your question. This is better than trying to add it as a comment. A worked example showing a short sample input CSV file and your expected output CSV would be good.

Comment: What is `clean_text`? Can you either supply a CSV file that actually works with your code or trim your code down to work with the provided CSV? The latter option is very much preferred.

Comment: clean_text is a function to remove unwanted charactors from CSV file data I have uploaded my CSV file: https://mobile-auto-services.com/feeds/LawnMowersUK.csv

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/5jPEnf/1) might help you to remove your repeated inputs in your CSV file using a string replace:

```
([\s\S]+)\1{1,}
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows that how it would work by back-referencing:

[image]